# Custom roles disappeared in the appliaction after java update on weblogic server

Tags: java, roles, weblogic12c

After updating java from version 1.8.0_301 to 1.8.0_361 on our Weblogic (12c) servers, custom roles for users on user profile page (IdcService=GET_USER_INFO) in the applications disappear. Only the basic roles stay. The custome roles and groups are still visible in Weblogic server administration console - Security Realms - myrealm.
Nothing other has changed.
When downgrading java back, everything is ok again.

I have no idea how to solve this so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oracle Support Document 2865542.1 (After Upgrading JDK In WCC Environment, WCC Users Lost Roles) can be found at: https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocumentDisplay?id=2865542.1